# How to remove SteamVR from Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam

I'm learning Unity.  I added SteamVR from the asset store to the project so that I can walk around the scene with the Vive.  Now I've removed the SteamVR folder from the project Assets folder.  However, when I load the project or run it, the SteamVR application starts, which starts up the VR headset and trackers, etc. and the Console says "OpenVR initialized!".  There is nothing in the Assets folder that references SteamVR or OpenVR.  How can I completely remove the association?

Comment: Have you removed the Plugins related to SteamVR ?
- openvr_api.bundle
- x86/libopenvr_api.so
- x86_64/libopenvr_api
- openvr_api.cs

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of Unity come with OpenVR support built in. You need to uncheck the box for "[Virtual Reality Supported](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html)" in your Player project settings.

[image]

[image]